# Let $A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb F)$. Is $\mathbb F^n$ the direct sum of $R(A)$ and $N(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb F)$. Is $\mathbb F^n$ the direct sum of $R(A)$ and $N(A)$ ?

If I could show that the orthogonal complement of $R(A)$ is $N(A)$ the result would follow, but the orthonal complement of $R(A)$ is $N(A^T)$ which aren't neccesarily equal to $N(A)$ ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessary that $$\Bbb F^n=R(A)\oplus N(A)$$
since it's possible that
$$R(A)\cap N(A)\ne\{0\}$$
and even we might find that
$$R(A)\subset N(A)$$
in the case when $A$ is nilpotent with index $2$.

Comment: Amen. Example: $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: In this case $R(A) = N(A)$. Do you also have an example where $R(A) \subset N(A)$ ? In this case $\subset$ means a proper subset ?

Comment: Take almost the same example but with matrix $3\times3$ or more.@user111854

Comment: @user111854 example was not referring to last line specifically, but counterexample to original question in general